# Aurelia custom Binding Behavior to observe ALL properties of an object

Tags: aurelia

I would like to create a custom Binding Behavior that allows me to detect ANY changes to the properties of an object, like this:

```
<my-form model.bind="myObject & objectObserver:myObjChanged()"></my-form>
```

I know that I can use Aurelia's binding engine to create a property observer, and perhaps I can build this into a custom Binding Behavior to detect the properties of the object and create property observers for each one.  But I can't make sense of the binding object that is given to me inside the custom Binding Behavior.  Here's my code so far:

```
import { inject, bindingBehavior, BindingEngine } from 'aurelia-framework';

@bindingBehavior('objectObserver')
@inject(BindingEngine)
export default class ObjectObserverBindingBehavior {
  constructor(bindingEngine) {
    this.bindingEngine = bindingEngine;
  }

  bind(binding, scope, interceptor) {
    console.warn('hello', binding, scope, interceptor);
  }

  unbind(binding, scope) {
    console.warn('observer.unbind()', binding, scope);
  }
}
```

When the bind happens and the console text is output, I see 
[image]

So I know it's working, but I don't know what the best object is to start watching.  I see the bound object inside targetObserver.currentValue.  Is that the best property to start watching?  Is there another way that utilizes existing functionality of the Aurelia Binding Engine?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212581/aurelia-notification-when-any-property-is-modified) might be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that is not Aurelia specific, based on the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) functionality built into Javascript.

```
export function onChangeObj(object, onChange) {
  // creates Proxy to detect changes in object properties and call a function
  if (typeof onChange !== 'function' || typeof object !== 'object') {
    throw new Error('onChangeObj: incorrect parameters');
  }
  const handler = {
    set(obj, prop, value) {
      onChange(prop, value);
      return Reflect.set(obj, prop, value);
    },
  };
  return new Proxy(object, handler);
}
```

In order to use it, just call it like this:

```
this.myObject = onChangeObj(this.myObject, () => this.myObjChanged());
```

Effectively, the object is replaced by a wrapper Proxy that calls the provided function every time one of the properties is modified (with the setter).

If anyone finds a solution via Aurelia Binding Behavior, I would still be interested.